# Should I use part participle form of every verb that follow "would have"?

Tags: grammaticality, past-participles, coordination

I wrote a sentence on my own jokingly.

> How cool would it be, if I could have infiltrated the Kremlin, steal the Tsar's throne and return to my peaceful home unharmed

Regarding that sentence my friend told me, it would have been grammatical if I wrote it in the following way

> How cool would it be, if I could have infiltrated the Kremlin, **stolen** the Tsar's throne and **returned** to my peaceful home unharmed

The **BOLD** parts are changed in the last sentence. The reason he told me was that the *could have* part should be followed by past participle form of every verbs. So as I had written "could have *infiltrated*", I should have used *stolen* and *returned* for the same reason. Is it true?

To me, if I could have *infiltrated* the Kremlin, I am like gone to the fictional time and now what I was about to do is like happening in the present *of that time*. So I used present tense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at it this way:

> How cool would it be if I could have infiltrated the Kremlin! (what
>   you already had)
>
> How cool would it be if I could have stolen the
>   Tsar's throne!
>
> How cool would it be if I could have returned home!

The 'present tense' alternatives are wrong:

> How cool would it be if I could have infiltrate the Kremlin!*
>
> How cool would it be if I could have steal the throne!*
>
> How cool would it be if I could have return home!*

As you see, the real problem is that "could have" is part of the verb phrase of infiltrate, and of steal, and of return.

Compare:

I had heard and seen him (correct).

I had heard and saw him* (incorrect).

I had heard him, but now I saw him (correct).

Comment: What is a verb phrase?

Comment: Wikipedia has a technical definition; I'm probably not quite using it correctly.  My point is just that "steal" and "return" are syntactically constrained by "could have", but it's easiest to explain by example.

Comment: @Mistu4u A verb phrase is a phrase with a verb as its head.  For example, in the sentence "I went to the store", the subject "I" is a noun phrase, and the predicate "went to the store" is a verb phrase.  The head of the noun phrase "I" is "I", and the head of the verb phrase "went to the store" is "went".